# what to do when your WordPress database is too large?

Tags: database, wordpress, godaddy

My WordPress site's database is nealy reaching 1GB which is the limitation of my host (GoDaddY), what should I do? I can't purchase a dedicated solution for it?

There must be a way out to split this database into 2 or, another way , can we use 2 database into a single WP installation?

What do you guys do on such case? Thanks.

Comment: @9grams: Off topic on SO?

Comment: A WP database with *1 Gigabyte*? What on earth are you storing in there? Is it all data for one blog?

Comment: @9grams: There is a dedicated Q & A site for wordpress, take a look here: wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

You may find that a lot of that space is being taken up by past revisions of posts. A plugin like [Delete Revision](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/delete-revision/) is a good way of managing this bloat.

Answer (score 4):

9grams,

The first step is to determine why the database is so large. Though not impossible, it's extremely unlikely that it needs to be that large. There's probably some plugin inefficiently or unnecessarily storing data. If you're not sure what's going on, it may help to access phpMyAdmin, a database management tool, to see what table in the database is taking up so much space. This would help you identify if it's a specific plugin. If you don't know how, [this help article explains](http://community.godaddy.com/help/article/5942?isc=smfor1) how to access phpMyAdmin from your GoDaddy.com account.

In my experience, it's often traffic statistics data that causes this problem. I have no way of knowing if that's the case for you, but if it is, I would recommend finding another solution for stats tracking and then removing the plugin and stats table that the plugin generated. There are many solutions out there which don't store the information in the database (including a service offered by Go Daddy), so you wouldn't have to sacrifice stats tracking, just find a new way to do it.

Alon
GoDaddy.com Social Media Team

Comment: It's great to see a representative from GoDaddy participating in our community. :)

Comment: Thanks Alon, indeed yes, it was Stats tracking plugin devouring around 460megs od MySQL data.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

1. delete revisions
2. old comments (say's older than N months)
3. buy bigger plan (or VPS).